# Error in mysql trigger insert into after insert

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have below trigger code on before insert but this gives me error when I trying to run on terminal.

```
    DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `user_has_voice_queues_rt_Insert`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `user_has_voice_queues_rt_Insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `user_has_voice_queues_rt` 
FOR EACH ROW 
if(new.penalty=0) THEN 
    Set new.guard_name = (select IFNULL(max(penalty),'0') as max from user_has_voice_queues_rt where penalty between 0 and 6999) + 1;
Else If(new.penalty=1) THEN
    Set new.guard_name = (select IFNULL(max(penalty), '7000') as max from user_has_voice_queues_rt where penalty between 7000 and 8999) + 1;
Else IF(new.penalty=2) THEN
    Set new.guard_name = (select IFNULL(max(penalty),'9000') as max from user_has_voice_queues_rt where penalty between 9000 and 9500) + 1;
Else IF(new.penalty=3) THEN
    Set new.guard_name = (select IFNULL(max(penalty),'9500') as max from user_has_voice_queues_rt where penalty between 9501 and 9999) + 1;
END IF
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

[image]

Comment: it was else if which needs to b elseif.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace all

```
else if
```

with

```
elseif
```

Comment: Can you help bit more. How can I enclose all the if-else-end in another nested if or case statement.

Comment: Just put it around: `if`... `else` ... `end if`

Comment: Then ask another question and add the code you tried to it. We will have a look

Comment: If you use a SQL tool like  *MySQL Workbench* it is way easier to resolve errors